# Pointer and Struct Issues

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am having trouble understanding why this piece of code is not working properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "runSolver.h"

typedef struct testStruct {
  double *x[11];
  double *u[10];
} Test;

typedef struct returnStruct_t {
  Test* vars;
} ReturnStruct;

void initalize_returnStruct(void** returnStruct){
  ReturnStruct* new_returnStruct = (ReturnStruct *)malloc(sizeof(new_ReturnStruct));
  Test* varsStruct = (Test*)malloc(sizeof(Test)*3);

  int dataSize = 5;
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    int x;
    for(x = 0; x < 11; x++){ 
      fprintf(stderr, "i:%d and x:%d for x\n", i, x);
      varsStruct[i].x[x] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*5);    
    }
    for(x = 0; x < 10; x++){
      fprintf(stderr, "i:%d and x:%d for u\n", i, x);      
      varsStruct[i].u[x] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*5);    
    }
  }

  new_returnStruct->vars = varsStruct;
  *returnStruct = new_returnStruct;
}
```

This function is called via python's `ctypes`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ctypes as ct

class returnStruct_t(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("vars", Test_t*3)]

runSolver = ct.CDLL('./runSolverParallel.so')

varsd = ct.c_void_p()
runSolver.initalize_returnStruct(ct.byref(varsd))
```

What I am trying to do is the following:

- pass in a void pointer to a pointer named `returnPointer`
- instantiate a pointer to type `ReturnStruct`
- instantiate a pointer to an array of size 3 of type `Test`
- instantiate `Test` structure's data members `x` and `u`
- have `returnPointer` point to the fully instantiated `ReturnStruct`

When I run the code as listed it segfaults on the first iteration of the second inner for loop when I am trying to allocate space for `new_returnStruct->vars[0].u[0]`. If I totally eliminate the decleartion of `double *u[10]` and its instatiation I get a segfault on the line where I set `returnPointer` to point to `ReturnStruct` : `*returnStruct = new_return;`. Honestly I am out of ideas as to what the hell is going on. Any help would be great.

PS: I am using `double *x[11]; double *u[10];` rather then, `double **x; double **u;`, because the struct `Test` is not the real struct I will using. The real struct is defined elsewhere in a library and has those two variables as well as about 20 some other `double *` variables. I want to eventually replace `Test` with that struct but I want to get this code working with `Test` first. Just for reference the real struct `Test` will be replaced with is:

```
typedef struct Vars_t {
  double *u_0; /* 1 rows. */
  double *u_1; /* 1 rows. */
  double *u_2; /* 1 rows. */
  double *u_3; /* 1 rows. */
  double *u_4; /* 1 rows. */
  double *u_5; /* 1 rows. */
  double *u_6; /* 1 rows. */
  double *u_7; /* 1 rows. */
  double *u_8; /* 1 rows. */
  double *u_9; /* 1 rows. */
  double *x_1; /* 5 rows. */
  double *x_2; /* 5 rows. */
  double *x_3; /* 5 rows. */
  double *x_4; /* 5 rows. */
  double *x_5; /* 5 rows. */
  double *x_6; /* 5 rows. */
  double *x_7; /* 5 rows. */
  double *x_8; /* 5 rows. */
  double *x_9; /* 5 rows. */
  double *t_01; /* 1 rows. */
  double *t_02; /* 1 rows. */
  double *t_03; /* 1 rows. */
  double *t_04; /* 1 rows. */
  double *t_05; /* 1 rows. */
  double *t_06; /* 1 rows. */
  double *t_07; /* 1 rows. */
  double *t_08; /* 1 rows. */
  double *t_09; /* 1 rows. */
  double *t_10; /* 1 rows. */
  double *x_10; /* 5 rows. */
  double *u[10];
  double *x[11];
} Vars;
```

Comment: i don't know how this even *compiles*. `return`, the name of the parameter to your first function listed, is a reserved word. Post the *real* code, complete with the `int main()` that generated the output you're presenting, along with the `#include` list at the top of the file, and any/all steps you'e taken to *debug* this. The back trace from `gdb` will likely speak volumes.

Comment: @WhozCraig Opps not sure how that got changed to `return`, it should be `returnStruct`. Also I am calling this function from python via `ctypes` so there is no `int main()`. I will post the python code though.

Comment: Well it segfaults because you're not allocating memory for `new_returnStruct->vars` before dereferencing this pointer. Also, you should use malloc(sizeof(*new_returnStruct)) instead of the current code in the first line, although it most likely is not cause of the crash.

Comment: Please, roll-back your edit to the revision the answers address. As it is, this question asks why working cord isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are allocating memory for ReturnStruct* pointer not the actual struct
Instead of

```
   ReturnStruct* new_returnStruct = (ReturnStruct *)malloc(sizeof(new_returnStruct));
```

try this

```
   ReturnStruct* new_returnStruct = (ReturnStruct *)malloc(sizeof(ReturnStruct));
```

Comment: Additionally, there is **no need** to cast `malloc`. Simply use: `ReturnStruct* new_returnStruct = malloc(sizeof(ReturnStruct));`

Answer (score 2):

There are some errors in your code:

This line hould be `ReturnStruct` and not `new_returnStruct` as parameter of `sizeof`:

```
ReturnStruct* new_returnStruct = (ReturnStruct *)malloc(sizeof(new_returnStruct));
```

Are you sure that `sizeof(Test) == sizeof(Pee)*3` or in fact, why you're using `Pee` instead of `Test` ?

```
Test* varsStruct = (Test*)malloc(sizeof(Pee)*3);
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with `varsStruct[i].x[0]` (it'd be invalid if `varsStruct` was a `Test **`). `sizeof varsStruct->x` is fine, `sizeof(double)*11` is definitely wrong (`sizeof(double *)*11` would also be correct).

Comment: I renamed `Pee` to `Test` for this posting. Just forgot to change it in that one spot. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Read the def of `varsStruct` : it is `Test*`. With `i = 1`, it segfault or do anything but what it should (however, even if I don't do C now, I'm pretty sure I'm not wrong on that one).

Comment: Also when I add the following changes: `varsStruct->x = (double**)malloc(sizeof(varsStruct->x));` I get an error: `runSolverParallel.c:34:19: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘double *[11]’ from type ‘double **’`

Comment: It might be out-of-bounds access, I don't know, the code in the question was edited multiple times. Compilers, however, don't check bounds. (Usually, they are allowed to where they can, of course; Gcc, for example, never does.)

Comment: @mafso The code thats up there right now is the one I tried it on if that helps. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Testing it (I'm on Windows, no gcc until I started my NAS), I see I was wrong on the `varsStruct[i].x[0]` and on the `double` malloc. This is valid because this is an array of Test. I removed both comment and part of answer that was wrong (and perhaps I should remove it as it is the same as the other answer). However, there is a part you omit, which is _what happens when memory allocation fails_.